# javascript array to php array_sum()

Tags: php, javascript

Cant seem to figure this out.. I have a JavaScript function that gets the value of all elements with the same class name:

```
var total = $(".bob").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();

var queryString = "?total="+total;
http.open("GET", "product.php" + queryString, true);

http.onreadystatechange = rgetHttpRes;
http.send(null);
```

I am passing the array to my php file -

```
if (isset($_GET['total'])) {
    $price = $_GET['total'];
    $num = array($price);
    $result = array_sum($num);
    echo($result);
}

// So I passed 2 integers with the JavaScript function: 15.99 and 10.99 into this  php function.
   It will only return one of them:  10.99 //
```

When I do this:

```
if (isset($_GET['total'])) {
    $price = $_GET['total'];
    $num = array($price);
    print_r($num);
}
```

this is the output I get:

```
Array ( [0] => 15.99, 10.99 )
```

I can't figure out why it wont print them like

```
Array ( [0] => 15.99 [1] => 10.99 )
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query is passed on as a string, you will need to use `explode` to convert it to an array

```
if(isset($_GET['total'])) {
    $price = $_GET['total'];
    $num = explode(",",$price);
    print_r($num);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i thought i had tried that.. You saved me a headache!

Answer (score 0):

how about this one ?

```
var t = $(".bob").size();
var ken = new Array();
var a;
for(a = 0;a<t;a++){
ken.push($(".bob").eq(a).val());
}
```